# Probability of duplicate values across multiple set.

Tags: probability

I am looking to calculate the probability a series of (theoretically random) numbers would produce duplicate row/series.  It is a spreadsheet of seven columns by 41,881 rows.  Each cell can have a potential random integer (n) ranging from 0-7,550.

| Data | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 | Col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R1 | n | n | n | n | n | n | n |
| ... | n | n | n | n | n | n | n |
| R41881 | n | n | n | n | n | n | n |

First question, if each integer can equal a random integer between 0-7,550 what is a good equation to calculate the odds (1 in x) two rows result in the integers across all columns?  Second question, what is a good equation to calculate the odds (1 in x) 55 rows result in the integers across all columns?

I came up with the following (((1/1,7550)^7)^55), but I fear I have a missing/misplaced factor.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: If each value is uniform i.i.d. over the $7550$ or $7551$ integers, you can find how many possible sequences there are, your $7550^7$.  You then essentially have the birthday problem but with this very large number of days and quite large number of people, so you may need an approximation.  Without doing the calculation I suspect in this case the probability of any duplicate rows will be very small.

Comment: For large $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$, a calculation that looks like $\displaystyle n^k$ can (very) easily be done on a computer, with logarithms.  Usually, one would use base $10$ or base $e$ (i.e. *natural*) logarithms.  **Alternatively**, if it is desired to manage a large integer $~\displaystyle \left[\text{e.g.} ~ > 10^{(50)}\right],~$ I know that Java has the BigInteger class, and I would guess that programming languages like C or Python have similar facilities.